# better exposed filters for block view

Tags: blocks, views

I have created a block view for filter options and tried to display the filter options as check boxes using Better Exposed Filters(BEF) but in the BEF settings i don't get check box option in select option list of  "display tid as" drop down. now how to solve dis problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the term reference field settings is set to "Dropdown" and Under views Other settings Use Ajax option is set to "Yes"

[image]
[image: term reference field setting set to dropdown]